# Update claims after login with identityserver3 2.1.1

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, claims, identityserver3

We need to update users claims after they log in to our website. This is caused by changes in the users licenses done by another part of our system.

However I am not able to comprehend how to update the claims without logout/login.

Rigth now this is our client setup

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //user validation host
            Authority = UrlConstants.BaseAddress,

            //Client that the user is validating against
            ClientId = guid,//if not convertet to Gui the compare from the server fails
            RedirectUri = UrlConstants.RedirectUrl,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = UrlConstants.RedirectUrl,
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile email roles licens umbraco_api umbracoaccess",

            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {

                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    _logger.Info("ConfigureAuth", "Token valdidated");

                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                               id.AuthenticationType,
                               Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                               Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                    // get userinfo data
                    var uri = new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo");
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(uri,n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                    var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                    userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));

                    var licens = id.FindAll(LicenseScope.Licens);
                    nid.AddClaims(licens);

                    // keep the id_token for logout
                    nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        nid,
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    _logger.Info("ConfigureAuth", "AuthenticationTicket created");



                },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                {
                    // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token").Value;
                        _logger.Debug("ConfigureAuth", "id_token for logout set on request");
                        _logger.Debug("ConfigureAuth", "Old PostLogoutRedirectUri: {0}", n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri.ToString());
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint;

                        var urlReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                        if (!urlReferrer.Contains("localhost"))
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = GetRedirectUrl();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = urlReferrer;
                        }

                        _logger.Debug("ConfigureAuth", string.Format("Setting PostLogoutRedirectUri to: {0}", n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri.ToString()));
                    }
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.AuthenticationRequest)
                    {
                        n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = GetRedirectUrl2();
                        n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = GetCurrentUmbracoId();
                        _logger.Debug("ConfigureAuth", string.Format("Setting RedirectUri to: {0}", n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri.ToString()));
                    }
                },


            }
        });
```

We get our custom claims in SecurityTokenValidated

```
 var licens = id.FindAll(LicenseScope.Licens);
                    nid.AddClaims(licens);
```

I do not follow how to get this without doing a login? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a reminder that you should not put claims into tokens that might change during the lifetime of the session.

That said - you can set a new cookie at any point in time.

Reach into the OWIN authentication manager and call the SignIn method. Pass the claims identity that you want to serialize into the cookie.

e.g.

`Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(newIdentity);`

Comment: Are you saying that claims local to a application could change during a session without any problem? We only get issues when claims change which are used by multiple applications.